# Runtime error (at -1:0): Cannot import ISSkin.dll with InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup, failed-installation

My program installs fine in my computer, which has ISSkin installed. I tried then to install my program in a different computer that has not got ISSkin installed and I get this message upon installation : **"Runtime error (at -1:0): Cannot import dll:c:\Folder00\ISSkin.dll".**

I searched on the net but nothing so far. I have the following code in my INNO:

```
[Files]
Source: "c:\Folder00\ISSkin.dll"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy; Attribs: hidden system

[Code] 
procedure LoadSkin(lpszPath: String; lpszIniFileName: String); external 'LoadSkin@c:\Folder00\ISSkin.dll cdecl';

procedure UnloadSkin();
external 'UnloadSkin@c:\Folder00\ISSkin.dll cdecl'
```

Im am using a *.cjstyles skin for the innosetup. I changed from STDCALL to CDECL but to no avail. Has anyone had this problem and how it can be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're extracting the dll to temporary files but trying to load it from some 'c:\folder00\', which most probably won't exist in the target computer.

Follow the [example](http://isskin.codejock.com/gettingstarted.asp) on the product page and you'll be fine. Relevant pieces from the linked example:

```
[Files]
Source: ISSkin.dll; DestDir: {app}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: Office2007.cjstyles; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy    

[Code] 
procedure LoadSkin(lpszPath: String; lpszIniFileName: String); external 'LoadSkin@files:isskin.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Office2007.cjstyles');
  LoadSkin(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Office2007.cjstyles'), '');
  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: +1, anyway, you don't need to specify `DestDir` with combination of `dontcopy` flag.

Comment: @TLama - AAMOF I didn't know about referencing a file like 'LoadSkin@files:isskin.dll stdcall' seemingly without the need to extract it. So I decided not to touch the example..

Comment: Thank you TLama (who gave me a first answer in a previous comment of a previous post hehehe) and also many thanks to Sertac for showing interest in the problem and for giving also the right solution :). It is working fine now !